# Using ARM or any microcontroller text output

Tags: microcontroller, serial, converter, output, vga

As you may notice, some microcontrollers have an output in textmode with four pin assigned to send serial data.
In some cases we may need to use this output for finding our problem,without forcing to pullout microcontroller and reprogram it, for example Linux based embedded devices.
I have searched internet for a device that can use this output and convert it to VGA port and find nothing except microvga.com.
As this device is not sold anymore Do you have any idea to purchase similar product or make it by myself.

Comment: Google for VGA Serial Terminal.

Comment: How would four pins output text data? Generally you would have an UART for debug and you could just connect it to a laptop, which would also be far more useful that just video output.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a USB-Serial dongle and display the output on a computer.

But since you're not talking about that, I guess you need something different.

If you want it to be included in the device, you could use a [LCD with serial input](https://www.sparkfun.com/tutorials/289). That's basically a LCD with a microcontroller that reads data from a serial port and displays it.

For debugging in the field, you can also plug a USB-serial dongle into your smartphone and use a serial terminal app. This should be more convenient than a 2-line LCD if the micro outputs lots of text.

Comment: I think this product is ok with my job,but it's out of stock now. Do you have another suggestion to constitute this device from another modules? For example,as far as my understanding suggests,a ttl serial or rs232 conversion module be used to transfer data to 16*2 display

Answer (score 1):

> I have searched internet for a device that can use this output and convert it to VGA port and find nothing except microvga.com.

VGA is ... kind of dead, but other than that: sounds like about any single-board linux-capable computer would do that job: plug in the UART from the microcontroller to a UART port on the SoC, configure the right baud rate / frame format and have it display the result (e.g. with minicom) on the screen.

Note that there's no standardized "serial output", you need to know or detect (or try) the right rates, frame formats and so on.

Comment: The microcontroller is oxford semiconductor oxe800dse in the heart of Western Digital world edition NAS.  Based on a hack method in the following address:       http://mybookworld.wikidot.com/hardware.     
It is possible to revive device by some operation on hdd. I tried that operations and default IP could not ping again. Now I must somehow interact with embedded Linux to read error message. As method suggests I should use microvga.com

Comment: that claim makes no sense at all. You need to interact. You need to attach a serial console using a PC-style computer, not something that connects to VGA.

Comment: Would you please take a look at this page again and Check how a PS2 keyboard and text monitor could do the job.   http://martin.hinner.info/mybook/monitor_tv.php

Comment: attached to a single board computer they could. I said that in my answer!